# Change color attribute for a hyperlink inside a div when div has a certain class

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to change the font color to `white` for a hyperlink inside a div, when the div has a certain class of `rgSelected` applied to it. Normally, without the `rgSelected` class, the hyperlink has a font color of red.

**Question**

How would I make sure that the font color of hyperlink is white when the div has a `rgselected` class applied to it, else make its font color `red`? I am not sure if this can be achieved by pure CSS or in combination with jQuery.

```
<div class="alternatingItem rgSelected">
   <a onclick="sendEmail()" style="color:red;">Employee1<a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need jquery for this. I am using important because you have inline style in `a` element and overwrite the one from the css rule.

```css
.rgSelected a {
  color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alternatingItem rgSelected">
  <a onclick="sendEmail()" style="color:red;">Employee1<a>
</div>
```

Comment: Though you're correct, it's worth noting you're using "direct descendant" selector here. It would work, given OPs example code, but may be a little too restrictive in other usages.

Comment: Either is fine; I may have read _"hyperlink inside a div"_ more casually, just wanted to bring attention to the detail.

Comment: Highly recommend to check [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Answer (score 3):

```
/* 
  set default `css` property of `.alternatingItem` child `a` `color` to `red`
  if `.alternatingItem` does not have `class` `rgSelected`
*/
.alternatingItem:not(.rgSelected) a {
  color:red;
}
/*
  if `.alternatingItem` has `class` `rgSelected` , set 
  child `a` `css` property `color` to `white`
*/
.alternatingItem.rgSelected a {
  color:white;
}
```

---

```js
function sendEmail() {}

$("a").click(function(e) {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass("rgSelected")
})
```

```css
.alternatingItem:not(.rgSelected) a {
  color: red;
}
.alternatingItem.rgSelected a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alternatingItem">
  <a onclick="sendEmail()">Employee1<a>
</div>
```

Comment: _Give a man a fish, he'll eat for a day. Teach a man to fish, he'll eat for the rest of his life._ -- Though supplying a solution is great, it's also nice to provide meaning/context/insight into that code as well.